# Pushing an upgrade to an app approved for sale but not released to AppStore

Tags: iphone, app-store

I currently have an app approved for Sale that has a release day set to a month from now. I want to add an extra feature to it before the release date.

Can I push an upgrade in during the time when the app is approved but non-live?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I push an upgrade in during the
>   time when the app is approved but
>   non-live?

Yes. You can push the release date of the new approved version even further in the future, and send Apple yet another version with the new features for review, which will replace the version in standby as soon as it's approved. That way the current version will never hit the App Store.

Comment: +1 Doing it as we speak and this is true. I also chose my app to be held for release, which means once approved I have to manually release it in order for it to appear in the store.

Answer (score 0):

No, the update still has to go through the app review process.

Comment: True, but there is nothing preventing you from uploading a new binary for approval before the app is released.

Comment: Yep - I assumed that the Q was about adding features without going through the approval process again / affecting the release timeline.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  I pushed out two updates to my app before it was released for sale.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit another update, but I believe that you lose your place in the approval queue.